# Getting default Calendar app to work with University account (outside auth)

Tags: calendar

I'm trying to get the default Calendar-App to work with my University Google calendar account. It requires an external Oauth login.

I tried to at least get read-only with ICal and I got Permission Denied.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go to your account preferences and find a link called App passwords. Click on it, and create a new password profile (name it whatever you want). Google will then generate a new password to use with the app instead of your usual log in password. Hope this helps.